# Is there selenium2 Chrome driver for Ruby/Python?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I want to use Selenium2 Chrome driver with Ruby/Python, but I only found those for Java and .NET on http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list . Could someone tell me is it possible to drive Chrome with Python or Ruby in Selenium2? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For python you have to download the chrome driver from http://code.google.com/p/chromium/downloads/list. Extract the zip file and set the chrome driver path in Path environment variable. Please see the below example using python -

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("http://www.google.com")

elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")

elem.send_keys("selenium")

elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

assert "Google" in driver.title

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

There definitely is for Python, you have to install the chrome driver, get it here for your appropriate OS: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/downloads/list.  to start up a chrome instance do this:

```
self.webdriver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=[path to chrome driver])
```